# How to mock a function returned by a mocked function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, web3js

I am trying to write mock a test for the following function call

```
const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract();

tx.data = await contract.methods
  .setup(
    [juryAddress, buyerAddress, sellerAddress],
    threshold,
    to,
    txData,
    fallbackHandler,
    paymentToken,
    0,
    sellerAddress
  )
  .encodeABI();
```

I am trying to mock this as a function `contract.methods.setup()` that returns a function object `encodeABI()` which then returns a dummy value `{}`.

The mock I am trying looks like this, although it is not working

```
const encodeABI = jest.fn()
encodeABI.mockReturnValue({})

const contract = {
    methods: {
        setup: jest.fn(),
    }
}

eth.Contract.mockResolvedValue(contract)
contract.methods.setup.mockResolvedValue(encodeABI)
expect(encodeABI).toBeCalled()
```

`expect(encodeABI).toBeCalled()` is not being called as I expect

Comment: [`mockResolvedValue()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue) returns a `Promise`. Are you sure you don't just want `contract.methods.setup.mockReturnValue(encodeABI)` instead?

Comment: @Phil I thought I would want to return a promise for `setup()`, since `contract.methods.setup()` is async, right?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be. Your code just calls `contract.methods.setup(...).encodeABI()`. If anything, it's `encodeABI()` that should return a `Promise` since that's what you are awaiting

Comment: thanks, you are right, I think I have it backwards then.  `contract.methods.setup()` returns a value, and `.encodeABI()` returns the Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your production code awaits `encodeABI()`, not `setup()`. It expects `setup()` to return an object with an `encodeABI()` function, not a `Promise`.

I would recommend making the following changes

```js
const encodeABI = jest.fn(async () => ({})) // return a Promise here

const contract = {
    methods: {
        setup: jest.fn(() => ({ encodeABI })) // return an object with encodeABI
    }
}
```